# concat() in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

here is my xml :

```
<compositeurs> 
    <compositeur></compositeur>
    <compositeur id="5">
        <dates naissance="1687" deces="1770"></dates>
        <nom>
            <prenom>Johann</prenom>
            <prenom>Sebastian</prenom>
            <prenom>Sebastian</prenom>
            <prenom>Sebastian</prenom>
            <famille>Bach</famille>
        </nom>
    </compositeur> 
        <pays>Alemagne</pays>
    <compositeur></compositeur>
</compositeurs>
```

I would like to concat all the elements prenom that have famille="Bach".

I used `concat(//nom[famille='Bach']/prenom)` but its wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do it in XPath 1.0

Here's the way to do it in XPath 2.0:

```
string-join(//nom[famille='Bach']/prenom, ' ')
```

If XPath 2.0 is unavailable, you can always concatenate the results of your original expression in whatever imperative language you're using.

Comment: I use Oxygen it's not available :\

Comment: @DalyChan AFAIK, Oxygen supports XPath 2.0. It's certainly [usable in XSL stylesheets](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/xslt_editor.html#xpathAwareCC)